# How do I print console.log on the front-end side with node.js and express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm learning node.js and express for a side-project.

How can I print `console.log();` on the client-side?

I'm working on a Hello project and I have the following code:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello from App Engine!');
});
```

Why do console.log() doesn't print in the client-side when I'm doing this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(console.log("test"));
});
```

Comment: You can't. Though, on client-side you can log the response you get from the server.

Comment: What is the client-side exactly? Is this my HTML page? Does it mean that I have to inject some javascript on my front page to listen to the server and log a response?

Comment: `res.send('console.log("test")');`

Comment: @KevinB Yes, but that will just print the text `console.log("test")`, not execute it on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send

`res.send` accepts an argument which is of the following types:

> a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array

`console.log` does not return anything and therefore nothing is passed to `res.send`. Instead, you can do the following:

```
res.send(`
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <body>
        <script>
          console.log(${ "test" /* this can be variable instead */ });
        </script>
     </body>
     </html>
`);
```

This will output a script element that will log something to the client console.

Comment: You should need to send a fully formed HTML page, not just a `<script>` tag.

Comment: And, the odds of encountering a client that can't handle stripping all the common tags is higher than the benefit achieved.  And, I see you silenty edited to add more than just the `<script>` tag.

Comment: @jfriend00 Fine, I fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`Console.log()` function expects either an *object* or a *string* parameter. So it is necessary to use single or double quotation marks  within `console.log()` whereas outside this function you just use the placeholder `${demovariable}`.
Here is what I believe the code should look like:

```
res.send(`
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
    <p>${demovariable}</p>
    <script>
      console.log('${demovariable}');
    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
`);
```